# Prove that for the Fibonacci sequence $(F_n)$, $F_n$ divides $F_{2n}$.

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I have a seemingly simple question to solve by induction. The question says $F_n$ divides $F_{2n}$ in the Fibonacci sequence. 
My thoughts on this.

First,since the n-th term of the Fibonacci sequence is given as the sum of the two previous terms, simple induction won't suffice.
So I should try composite induction.

That is, supposing that $F_k$ divides $F_{2k}$ for all $k<n$, I must prove $F_{n}$ divides $F_{2n}$.
Is this approach valid?

Doesn't seem to work. If I write $F_{2n}=F_{2n-1}+F_{2n-2}$ then by the inductive hypothesis, $F_{n-1}$ divides $F_{2n-2}$ but this does not help me assert that $F_n$ divides $F_{2n}$. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: See for example [understanding Fibonacci Fast Doubling Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124590/need-help-understanding-fibonacci-fast-doubling-proof) which also gives you the quotient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [$F_{m+n} = F_{n-1}F_m+F_nF_{m+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11477/showing-that-an-equation-holds-true-with-a-fibonacci-sequence-f-nm-f-n-1) with $m=n$, we have
$$F_{2n} = F_{n-1}F_n+F_nF_{n+1} = F_n\left(F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}\right)$$

So $F_n$ divides $F_{2n}$.

Answer (score 9):

My favorite Fibonacci technique is
the [matrix formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form), which is well worth knowing and [easily proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/proof-of-this-result-related-to-fibonacci-numbers):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}F_{2n+1}&F_{2n}\\F_{2n}&F_{2n-1}\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{2n}
=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{n}
 \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{n}
=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
Now look at the $(1,2)$ entries and get:
$$
F_{2n} = F_n(F_{n+1}+F_{n-1})
$$

Comment: Thanks, looks impressive.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Try to prove $\gcd(F_m, F_n) = F_{\gcd(m,n)}$ using induction. You might need these intermediate steps:

1. $\gcd(F_n, F_{n+1}) = 1.$
2. $F_{m+n}=F_mF_{n+1}+F_{m−1}F_n.$

Comment: $F_{m+n}=F_mF_{n+1}+F_{m−1}F_n$ is enough:  just take $m=n$.

Answer (score 5):

$n$th term of the Fibonacci sequence is given by$\sqrt{5}F_n=\varphi^n-(-\varphi)^{-n},$ where $\varphi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}.$ Now write $F_{2n}$ and factor it as a difference of two squares to reach the desire result.

Even though my proof goes without induction, if you really need, you can use induction to derive [the Binet's formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)