# How to prove $F_{n+1}^2 - F_{n-1}^2 = F_{2n} $ by combinatorial-proofs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers, combinatorial-proofs

I'm working on a problem that asks us to prove for any n $\geq$ 1, $F_n$ the Fibonacci number satisfy $F_{n+1}^2 - F_{n-1}^2 = F_{2n}$.

I learned Fibonacci identity $F_{2n} = F_{1}+F_{3}+F_{5}+...+F_{2n-1}$ by combinatorial-proofs but I don't know how to deal with the LHS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have $F_{2n} = F_n(F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}) = (F_{n+1}-F_{n-1})(F_{n+1}+F_{n-1})=F_{n+1}^2 - F_{n-1}^2$.

For a proof of the first equality, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2668266/589).

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$\mathcal{F} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$\mathcal{F}_n =
\begin{pmatrix}
F_{n+1}\\
F_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

we have
$$\mathcal{F}_{n+1} = \mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}_n$$
so
$$\mathcal{F}^n = 
\begin{pmatrix}
F_{n+1} & F_n\\
F_n     & F_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

now write $\mathcal{F}^{2n} = \mathcal{F}^n \mathcal{F}^n$
we deduce among other identities
\begin{align}
F_{2n} &= F_nF_{n+1} + F_nF_{n_1}\\
       &= F_n\left(F_{n+1} + F_{n-1}\right)\\
       &= \left(F_{n+1} - F_{n-1}\right)\left(F_{n+1} + F_{n-1}\right)\\
       &= F_{n+1}^2 - F_{n-1}^2
\end{align}